# How to show images after uploading with Plupload without page refreshing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plupload

Plupload/paperclip/rails 3.1.4/ruby 1.9.3

i successfully upload multiple images with Plupload, and as usual i've put in 'images/create.js.erb' code, which appends images to page.

nothing happens. even primitive alert has no visual response, but i hear how my hard disk grunts (actually i made endless cycle of alerts to hear that something happens inside :)

**images_controller**

```
def create
  @image=Image.create(:photo => params[:file])
  respond_to :js
end
```

**views/images/create.js.erb**

```
$('body').append('<%= escape_javascript(image_tag(@image.photo.url(:medium))) %>');
```

after each image creating, it must appear on page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the answer.

**views/images/create.js.erb**

```
<%=@image.id %>:<%= @image.photo.url(:medium) %>
```

**views/items/_form.js.erb**

```
<script>
... 
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, info) {
        var response = info['response'].split(':');
        var image_id= response[0];
        var image_url= response[1];
        ...
        use it as you want, my lord!..
        ...    
});
...
</script>
```